# Swagger 2.0 - Payload with list of orders

Tags: swagger-2.0

I would like to form my payload with following JSON according to **Swagger 2.0** specifications. Could you please suggest sample swagger to pre-populate?

```
orders : {
  order: {
    [
      id: 111,
      number: 111,
      itemName: "ItemNameOne",
      ...
    ],
    [
      id: 222,
      number: 222,
      itemName: "ItemNameTwo",
      ...
    ],
    [
      id: 333,
      number: 333,
      itemName: "ItemNameThree",
      ...
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Appreciated for your help.

Here is my sample swagger which allows me to add simple order but I would like to have multiple orders in same object as mentioned above.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Orders
paths:
  /pushorders:
    post:
      summary: Push Orders
      description: Push Orders
      parameters:
        - name: orders
          in: body
          required: true
          description: Push Orders
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/orders'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
definitions:
  orders:
    type: object
    properties:
      order:
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/order'
  order:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: number
        description: id
        default: 111
      number:
        type: number
        description: id
        default: 111
      itemName:
        type: string
        description: item name
        default: ItemNameOne
```

Comment: do you mean model?

Comment: @AnirudhBagri, Yes.

Comment: any particular language for which you want to create a model? there are many converters for Json to a language class.

Comment: No specific language but it works with either PHP or Java Script. I have also updated my sample swagger in my main post.

Comment: I do not require any script to parse swagger but works with sample swagger like I have mentioned in main post which should show list of orders from editor.swagger.io

Comment: See [Return an array of object in Swaggerhub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167981/return-an-array-of-object-in-swaggerhub) - it explains how to add an array example containing multiple items.

Comment: Hi @Helen, I will give a try. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Looks like it does not work as would require multiple objects to be captured in payload.