# Howto define an unwrapped XML response with OpenAPI

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I want to write a RESTful webserver which serves the following XML document:

```
<Services>
<TileMapService title="TMS server" version="1.0.0" href="/tms/1.0.0"/>
<TileMapService title="TMS server" version="1.0.1" href="/tms/1.0.1"/>
</Services>
```

I use the [OpenAPI Generator Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin) to generate model classes for my SpringBoot RestController.

```
openApiGenerate {
  generatorName = "spring"
  ...
  configOptions = [
    withXml: "true",
    ...
  ]
}
```

with the following openapi.yaml spec file:

```
...
"paths" : {
  "/tms" : {
    "get" : {
      "operationId" : "getServices",
      "responses" : {
        "200" : {
          "content" : {
            "text/xml" : {
              "schema" : {
                "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/ServicesRoot"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"components" : {
    "schemas" : {
      "ServicesRoot" : {
        "xml" : {
          "name" : "Services"
        },
        "properties" : {
          "TileMapServices" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/TileMapService"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "TileMapService" : {
        "xml" : {
          "name" : "TileMapService"
        },
        "properties" : {
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "xml" : {
              "attribute" : true
            }
          },
          "version" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "xml" : {
              "attribute" : true
            }
          },
          "href" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "xml" : {
              "attribute" : true
            }
          }
        }
      },
...
```

The generator creates a `ServicesRoot` model class from this spec. When I use this model with my RestController to create a response I get:

```
<Services>
  <TileMapServices>
    <TileMapServices title="TMS server" version="1.0.0" href="/tms/1.0.0"/>
    <TileMapServices title="TMS server" version="1.0.1" href="/tms/1.0.1"/>
  </TileMapServices>
</Services>
```

Can you please help me to solve the following problems:

1. The `TileMapService` array items are wrapped inside a `<TileMapServices>` XML-element. I need the array items "unwrapped" within the `</Services>` parent XML-element.
2. The array items XML-Element name is "pluralized" as `<TileMapServices .../>` with a trailing "s".

I want to use the generated model class as response object for the RestController and with Jackson XMLMapper to serialize XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

So your service is returning JSON.  My answer assumes Java and Spring Boot based on you using Gradle and a generator.

To get XML, have a look at this: [Spring-boot return json and xml from controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790998/spring-boot-return-json-and-xml-from-controllers)

It shows the Maven/Gradle dependency to add to the project for XML output and related configuration.

To "adjust" the marshalling, you need to use something like

```
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
```

or

```
    @JsonProperty("X")
```

For some guidance on that see: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization.

You may need to create a specific DTO to return rather than an internal model to more directly control marshalling with the above annotations.

Hopefully, this gets you started.

My appologies.  I misread your post.

Did you see this post:

[How to define an array of objects in OpenAPI 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63738715/how-to-define-an-array-of-objects-in-openapi-3-0)

In it, they use 'unwrapped'.

```
components:        
  schemas:
    abc:
      xml:
        wrapped : true    <<--- here!  set to false?
        name: abc
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        xml:
          name: 'item'
        properties: 
          Name:
            type: string
          age:
            type: integer
          enabled: 
            type: boolean
      example:
        - Name: no1
          age: 18
          enabled: true
        - Name: no2
          age: 20
          enabled: false
```

Comment: The service is returning XML. I cannot edit the DTO because it is generated from an openapi.yaml spec file and will be overwritten by the generator. I am looking for a generator config or spec file syntax which generates the DTO so that the RestController generates the correct XML document with it.