# How to declare a 'List<MyOwnType>' in an OpenAPI/Swagger-file?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

How declare a 'List' in an OpenAPI/Swagger-file?

```
The below code has generated List<String>

myTestProperty:
    type: array
    items:
        type: string

But not sure how to generate List<MyOwnType>.
```

Is there a way in OpenAPI to accomplish it? The resulting pojo must have that field.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [How to return an array of objects in OpenAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46167981/113116)

Comment: Yes it answers. Thank you.