# Unable to add ArrayList in swagger

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I want my OpenAPI spec to display the list of both the objects like below but I'm unable to do so.

```json
[
  {
    "studentID": 1,
    "studentName": "Ram"
  },
  {
    "studentID": 2,
    "studentName": "Shyam"
  }
]
```

Swagger Spec in editor.swagger.io:

[image]

Comment: Also: [How to return an array of objects in SwaggerHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46192564/113116)

Answer (score 0):

`example` keyword should be at the same level of `items`:

```
200:
  description: success response
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          properties:
            studentID:
              type: integer
            studentName:
              type: string
        example:
          - { "studentID": 1, "studentName": "Ram" }
          - { "studentID": 2, "studentName": "Shyam" }
```